# cmd shows Older version of Python, and IDLE shows the current version

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, cmd, python-idle

Here in cmd show this older version
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NE2oF.png)

but, IDLE shows this version (which i again installed)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfcMq.png)

because of this VsCode uses older verison of Python instead of Current version
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caWd9.png)

i tried setting path, but it still shows the older verison of python, uninstalled and installed it too.

in setting, Current version of is interpreter selected ,then also it runs program on older version
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MFOZ.png)

if by mistake there is two version of python, how do i get rid of older version of Python

i just want to use newer version of python

Edit:

it works, when i "Run Python File",(on current version), **Any way to set this as default?**

but, when i "Run Code" (ctrl + shift + N), it opens new terminal and runs that code in older version of python

i didn't installed two versions ,it was just as possibility .

but, there was python 10.12  present in Bin folder of MSYS2 .
[image: i don't have any idea, of that python in bin folder]

Comment: This is really a Windows question, not a programming question, and not an IDLE question.  Go to Add/Remove programs (enter 'remove' in Start search bar, lower left of screen).  Click Python 10.12 in list (takes a minute to fill) and then Uninstall.

Comment: _if by mistake there is two version of python_ What do you mean "by mistake"?  You installed both versions, didn't you?

Comment: Oh , there was python 10.12  present in Bin folder of MSYS2 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer, thanks to Mr. Terry Jan Reedy
there was python older version (see image)

[image: i just deleted these python files and now Vscode runs program on Newer version of Python]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you have chosen the Python3.11 as VSCode Python Interpreter, you can use shortcuts **Ctrl+Shift+`** or VSCode command **Terminal: Create New Terminal** to open a new terminal. Another way is delete the current terminal, and click the button "Run Python File" to run any python file.

[image]

Vscode will automatically activate the one you have selected.

If you're using **code-runner** extension, you can add the following codes to your `settings.json` to set the default interpreter:

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "python": "python"
}
```

Comment: it works, when i "Run Python File",(on current version), **Any way to set this as default?**
but, when i "Run Code" (ctrl + shift + N), it opens new terminal and runs that code in older version of python

Comment: @BlueBon That button or shortcuts is provided by Code-Runner extension, which is not supported by Microsoft. I‘ve updated my answer, you can check it.